# "Object object" bug when trying to render stepper PrimeVue in razor .cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, vuejs2, razor-pages, primevue

I installed PrimeVue library for my Vue.js app that it's inside of a .NET solution, and when I try to render the Steps component from PrimeVue v2 [text](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue-v2/#/steps), the Object Object error appears

Tag used for render the component:

`<stepper-component></stepper-component>`

The configuration of the Step component in the .cshtml file.

```html
<script asp-location="Footer" asp-order="300">
    Vue.component('stepper-component', {
        template: `
            <div>
                   <Steps :models="items" :activeIndex="currentStep"></Steps>
                   <button v-if="currentStep > 0" @@click="prevPage">Anterior</button>
                   <button v-if="currentStep < items.length - 1" @@click="nextPage">Siguiente</button>
                   <button v-if="currentStep === items.length - 1" @@click="complete">Finalizar</button>
            </div>
        `,
        data() {
            return {
                items: [
                    { label: 'Personal', to: '/steps' },
                    { label: 'Seat', to: '/steps/seat' },
                    { label: 'Payment', to: '/steps/payment' },
                    { label: 'Confirmation', to: '/steps/confirmation' }
                ],
                currentStep: 0,
                formObject: {}
            }
        },
        methods: {
            nextPage() {
                if (this.currentStep < this.items.length - 1) {
                    this.currentStep++;
                    window.Router.push(this.items[this.currentStep].to);
                }
            },
            prevPage() {
                if (this.currentStep > 0) {
                    this.currentStep--;
                    window.Router.push(this.items[this.currentStep].to);
                }
            },
            complete() {
                this.$toast.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Order submitted', detail: 'Dear, ' + this.formObject.firstname + ' ' + this.formObject.lastname + ' your order completed.' });
            },
            isActive(item) {
                if (item.route) {
                    let currentPath = window.Router.currentRoute.path;
                    return item.route === currentPath;
                }
                return false;
            },
        }
    });
</script>
```

What I try recently was to isolate the problem, initializing a pure vue app and render the Steps component, and it works. The difference is that in the pure Vue App I render  the Steps component inside a template and calling the property "model" instead of `:items="items"` how I called in the .cshtml razor file. You may ask why the difference, well, it's because if i use `:model="items"` in the .cshtml file, it renders lines of comments.

[Proof of the Object object in the .cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEYI9.png)

[Rendering in the pure Vue app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7wK3.png)

[What I expected in the .cshtml razor page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUubT.png)

[Currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chOun.png)

Comment: What is _"the Object Object"_ error?  Is it well known?  If so, provide a link, please.  What is the significance of of `[object Object]` in your source?  The word `object` is a reserved word in C#.  `System.Object` (often just `Object`) is a .NET type (though if `System` is not an included namespace, `Object` is just an identifier - though it's one I would never use).  Please include all your source as text, formatted as code.  Also, read in the help about how to format your code as `code`.  What do you mean by _"aislate"_?  Perhaps _translate_ or _isolate_?